# Using Eclipse Palantir TypeScript Plug-in with JSPM

Tags: eclipse-plugin, typescript, npm, jspm

I am using the [Palantir Eclipse TypeScript Plug-in](https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript) (v1.8.0.v20160223-1645), it works fine as long as my `d.ts` files are in the same source folder `/src` **but** due to JSPM they are in another folder and it cannot find and import the modules anymore:

```
/src                      <-- My .ts files are here (no js here)
/dist                     <-- This is where the transpiled js ends up
/jspm_packages/npm        <-- External d.ts files are here
```

In the project TypeScript properties (Eclipse UI), I have:

```
Source folder(s):       src
Exported folders(s):    src;jspm_packages/npm
Output folder:          dist
Output file name:       (nothing here)
```

So in `com.palantir.typescript.prefs` there is:

```
...
build.path.exportedFolder=src; jspm_packages/npm
build.path.sourceFolder=src
compiler.outputDirOption=dist
...
```

Answer (score 4):

(author of Eclipse TypeScript here) I think you'll want to add jspm_packages/npm to the source folders. You probably don't need the exported folders - those are for exporting things out of a project and only get used in multi-project workspaces where projects depend upon one another.

Comment: Thanks, I do not have time to check this right now, but one thing you could add is indicate somehwere in the UI which separator to use if you have multiple folders (namely semi-colon `;`)